# Error: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start" (Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, chart

I am trying to print a NO2 time series at a user specified point. However, this time series keeps saying:

> Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start".

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
// Function That applies scaling factor
function scale(image) {
  return  image.multiply(1000000)
}

//2019
var NO2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
  .select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-05-31')
  .map(scale)

// Make predefined data layers that can be selected.
var palettes = require('users/gena/packages:palettes');
var palette = palettes.colorbrewer.BrBG[11].reverse();

var NO2_band_viz = {
  min: 30,
  max: 300,
  palette: palette,
  opacity: 0.8
};

var composite = NO2.mean().visualize(NO2_band_viz);
var compositeLayer = ui.Map.Layer(composite).setName('NO2 Composite');

// Create the main map and set the SST layer.
var mapPanel = ui.Map();
var layers = mapPanel.layers();
layers.add(compositeLayer, '2019-20 Composite');


/*
 * Panel setup
 */

// Create a panel to hold title, intro text, chart and legend components.
var inspectorPanel = ui.Panel({style: {width: '30%'}});

// Create an intro panel with labels.
var intro = ui.Panel([
  ui.Label({
    value: 'NO2 - Time Series Inspector',
    style: {fontSize: '20px', fontWeight: 'bold'}
  }),
  ui.Label('Click a location to see its time series of NO2.')
]);
inspectorPanel.add(intro);

// Create panels to hold lon/lat values.
var lon = ui.Label();
var lat = ui.Label();
inspectorPanel.add(ui.Panel([lon, lat], ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal')));

// Add placeholders for the chart and legend.
inspectorPanel.add(ui.Label('[Chart]'));
inspectorPanel.add(ui.Label('[Legend]'));


/*
 * Chart setup
 */

// Generates a new time series chart of SST for the given coordinates.
var generateChart = function (coords) {
  // Update the lon/lat panel with values from the click event.
  lon.setValue('lon: ' + coords.lon.toFixed(2));
  lat.setValue('lat: ' + coords.lat.toFixed(2));

  // Add a dot for the point clicked on.
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
  var dot = ui.Map.Layer(point, {color: '000000'}, 'clicked location');
  // Add the dot as the second layer, so it shows up on top of the composite.
  mapPanel.layers().set(1, dot);

  // Make a chart from the time series.
  var NO2Chart = ui.Chart.image.series(NO2, point, ee.Reducer.mean());

  // Customize the chart.
  NO2Chart.setOptions({
    title: 'NO2: time series',
    vAxis: {title: 'NO2'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Date', format: 'MM-yy', gridlines: {count: 7}},
    series: {
      0: {
        color: 'blue',
        lineWidth: 0,
        pointsVisible: true,
        pointSize: 2,
      },
    },
    legend: {position: 'right'},
  });
  // Add the chart at a fixed position, so that new charts overwrite older ones.
  inspectorPanel.widgets().set(2, NO2Chart);
};


/*
 * Legend setup
 */

// Creates a color bar thumbnail image for use in legend from the given color
// palette.
function makeColorBarParams(palette) {
  return {
    bbox: [0, 0, 1, 0.1],
    dimensions: '100x10',
    format: 'png',
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    palette: palette,
  };
}

// Create the color bar for the legend.
var colorBar = ui.Thumbnail({
  image: ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select(0),
  params: makeColorBarParams(NO2_band_viz.palette),
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal', margin: '0px 8px', maxHeight: '24px'},
});

// Create a panel with three numbers for the legend.
var legendLabels = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [
    ui.Label(NO2_band_viz.min, {margin: '4px 8px'}),
    ui.Label(
        (NO2_band_viz.max / 2),
        {margin: '4px 8px', textAlign: 'center', stretch: 'horizontal'}),
    ui.Label(NO2_band_viz.max, {margin: '4px 8px'})
  ],
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal')
});

var legendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'Map Legend: median NO2 (2019-2020)',
  style: {fontWeight: 'bold'}
});

var legendPanel = ui.Panel([legendTitle, colorBar, legendLabels]);
inspectorPanel.widgets().set(3, legendPanel);

/*
 * Map setup
 */

// Register a callback on the default map to be invoked when the map is clicked.
mapPanel.onClick(generateChart);

// Configure the map.
mapPanel.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair');


// Initialize with a test point.
var initialPoint = ee.Geometry.Point(-73.725, 40.435);
mapPanel.centerObject(initialPoint, 4);


/*
 * Initialize the app
 */

// Replace the root with a SplitPanel that contains the inspector and map.
ui.root.clear();
ui.root.add(ui.SplitPanel(inspectorPanel, mapPanel));

generateChart({
  lon: initialPoint.coordinates().get(0).getInfo(),
  lat: initialPoint.coordinates().get(1).getInfo()
});
```

code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/283f84254b5a1e5aef5cdc6a084c0333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply functions such as `multiply()` on an image, it loses its associated properties. Copy the properties of the original image to the new image:

```
// Function That applies scaling factor
function scale(image) {
  return  image.multiply(1000000).set(image.toDictionary(image.propertyNames()))
}
```

Comment: awesome! that worked and my chart shows but now my map layer won't load? do you know what the cause of this is? @Kuik

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too. Thought it was just on my device... [This](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3dd3cd5866a18a716a936eddd600f819) is a bit faster and works when waiting ~2 minutes, and faster once cashed. If you apply scale on all images, ~27300 are first multiplied. Seems unnecessary

Comment: Hi @aewindle - it looks like this answer satisfies your question and has little room for debate. Would you mind accepting the answer (click check mark below the vote tally) so question browsers can quickly identify it as a complete Q&A.